# No entries in Amazon App Store on new (refurbished) Fire phone

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, amazon-appstore

I got a refurbished Fire phone. When accessing the Amazon App Store, I get an empty page. Searching the App Store delivers zero results for every query. Looking at the Amazon App Store on the web shows that the Fire phone cannot be selected as a device.

On the internet, I cannot find any information that Amazon has stopped to support the discontinued Fire phone in the App Store.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Pointer: Our [alternative-markets tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info). F-Droid would be a good choice (all FOSS, and [additional repositories](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/list-of-fdroid-repos) available).

Comment: The Amazon app store should work fine on that device... try clearing the data on the app and trying again, or manually update the Amazon App Store from http://www.amazon.com/getappstore You can also install the Google Play Store with info from http://spinyourfire.com/fire-phone-tips-and-tricks/turn-fire-phone-into-android-phone/

Comment: @acejavelin tried all, but it doesn't help. if i use getappstore, i get directed to the installed appstore and that does display an empty screen. i cleared the cache, deactivated the appstore, reset the app store and activated it again, but stll get an empty screen on the appstore. i cannot try any other solution, as all require the installation of some software from the app store. i am a customer with amazon.de, but with kindle-us (because some years ago i purchased a kindledx with international delivery) i don't want to change this setting, but maybe it is the cause of my problem??

Comment: @dnz I am not sure, but all Amazon accounts are connected somehow... I can use my US credentials on Amazon Japan and UK. Full factory reset?

Comment: well, i was able to install f-droid, now i have a file manager and will be able to install google play. i don't like to do a factory reset, so i will simply forget the amazon app store and hope that i still get updates for the preinstalled amazon apps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the Kindle account belonging to Amazon US (amazon.com) and the Amazon account belonging to Amazon Germany (amazon.de).

With a new Amazon account, all works fine.